# How to place a img in the right bottom corner of a div

Tags: html, css

[alt text http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/7514/unbenanntax.jpg](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/7514/unbenanntax.jpg)

This is what I want to do. A Div with some text in it and on the right bottom corner a img. The hight of the div is stable at 24px but the length is not known and there could be more than one of this divs In a row.

Comment: You could also try a `background-image`.

Comment: Related : [Attach images on all four corner of DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306087/attach-images-on-all-four-corner-of-div) & [Smart way to add corner image to DIV border on all four corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467063/smart-way-to-add-corner-image-to-div-border-on-all-four-corners).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a couple of techniques of doing this. The simplest:

```
<div class="outer">
<img src="....">
</div>
```

with

```
div.outer { position: relative; height: 24px; }
div.outer img { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

Now that takes it out of the normal flow, which is a problem is you want other content to wrap/float around it. In that case you really need to know the height of the image and then apply appropriate tricks depending on what you've got.

Start with [Making the absolute, relative](http://stopdesign.com/archive/2003/09/03/absolute.html).

If the image is 10 pixels high, for example, you could try this:

```
div.outer { height: 24px; }
div.outer { float: right; margin-top: 14px; }
```

Of course 14px comes from 24px - 10px. I don't know if that will satisfy what you're trying to achieve however.

Comment: so defenetly thx - about the 1st code - just bottom:0 with right positioning

Comment: I can not comment the answer from Cletus, but I have had to add "px" to "right: 0; bottom: 0;" so it is: right: 0px; bottom: 0px; In my case if I put something different of `0` without the `px` suffix it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Background image is your solution.

```
<div class="blarg" style="background:url(image.gif) bottom right no-repeat">Content</div>
```

You may need to adjust paddings of the div, too, so the contents of the div doesn't overlap your picture, if this is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to float the text around the image, both of those answers are wrong. Both will make the text go right over the image. I have been looking for hours and no real answer appears to exist. [This article](http://ask.metafilter.com/43977/How-do-I-float-an-image-to-the-lower-right-while-still-preserving-text-flow) more clearly explains why both of those answer will not work if your attempting wrapping the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='main'>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div class="img-div">
      <img src="....">
    </div>
</div>


div.main { 
   height: 1164px;
   width: 900px; 
}
div.img-div {
   position: absolute;
   top: 1084px;
   left: 817px;
   margin: .75rem;
}
```

Assuming dimensions of the image are 57*55

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Only for positioning an image at the bottom right corner:**
I have "Div" and image in the div and small image in the bottom right corner of the div.

[image]
**Detailed:**
https://jsfiddle.net/ez08vL7w/

```
       <html>
        <head> 
        </head>
        <body> 
<div style=" position:relative; display: inline-block">
  <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; z-index: 4; bottom: 50px; right: 30px; " 
    src="http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529736576495-1ed4a29ca7e1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max"/>
            
   <a href ="" target="_blank"> 
    <img src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/tiger-portrait-picture-id949472768?s=612x612"/> </a>
            
            </div> 
            </body> 
        </html>
```

**Simplified:**

```
<div style=" position:relative; display: inline-block">
      <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; z-index: 4; bottom: 50px; right: 30px; " 
        src=""/> 

        <img src=""/>  
          </div>
```