# Smart way to add corner image to DIV border on all four corners

Tags: css, border

My designer has designed a border with a diamond shape on the border corners. See image below.

[image: Diamond Border]

The way I'd go about achieving this would be to save the diamond shape as an image, create a 1px solid border and then place the diamond shape absolutely positioned on the four corners. While this works I'm sure there is a much smarter way to do this without the additional mark up.

Maybe using something like :after in css? How would I do this, or is there a better way? I need to have this compatible with IE8+ but if it works with IE7+ even better.

Comment: I would just use your current solution. CSS3 would come with stuff to make this 'better' however not all browsers (fully) support it yey.

Comment: do you plan to have always the same size (or one size for landscape and one for portrait) for every photo on your site?

Comment: The image inside the div is just an example. It may not be an image it may be text and it may expand based on what content thats inside

Comment: :after and :before would work if you only required two corners or you were working with a fixed width. As far as I know, IE7+ supports the :before and :after pseudo classes

Comment: @alex - It will be a fixed width. The height is not fixed. do you have a solution?

Comment: [`:before` and `:after` don't work in IE7](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/). That's the problem here. If IE7 support was not required, you could use an additional wrapper element and `:before` / `:after` for the corners.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a solution that's widely compatible, I think you should use four elements with [`position: absolute` combined with `position: relative`](http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) and negative offsets:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/M4TC5/

@meo's demo using `transform`: http://jsfiddle.net/M4TC5/2/
(and my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M4TC5/1/)

That really just shows the concept, you can generate better `transform` code (that doesn't look slightly "off" in IE) with this tool: http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

**HTML**:

```
<div class="image">
    <span class="corner TL"></span>
    <span class="corner TR"></span>
    <span class="corner BL"></span>
    <span class="corner BR"></span>
    <img src="???" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image {
    position: relative
}
.corner {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(???);
}
.TL {
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px
}
.TR {
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px
}
.BL {
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -10px
}
.BR {
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -10px
}
```

Comment: I didn't actually notice that you noted this idea in your question. Oh well. If you need IE7 support, then this is what I'd do. Otherwise, I'd probably go for an `:after` based solution.

Comment: is there any other method that doesn't require as much markup and will get IE7? If not please say and I will accept that there isnt any better way.

Comment: @sandeep - My markup is almost identical to thirtydot's answer.

Comment: @brady;ok it's height & width are dynamic or static.

Comment: @sandeep - the width is fixed the height is dynamic

Comment: i would not use a BG image you can set them a gray border to, and rotate them. And yes it works in IE to ;) http://css3please.com/

Comment: @meo: That's a valid point. I'm updating my answer to include it.

Comment: Love the idea there meo. Ok it doesnt cut down on markup but it cuts down on an image file so its an improvement. Please post this as an answer and the green tick goes to you.

Comment: anyway to make the squares look more diamond shape rather than rotated squares?

Comment: @brady: You need to use something like `rotate(45deg) skew(10deg)` as input to the tool in my answer.

Comment: @brady: Thinking about it a bit more, I wouldn't go with `transform` here. I'd just add the diamond image to my [sprite image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3) - no extra HTTP request.

Comment: the skew method doesnt look so good so gonna stick with the extra markup and image. Yes the image will be part of a sprite :)