# How to place an image outer of a div but on the right side

Tags: css

I try to show an image (representing a text showed vertically) on the right side of a div. As you can see on the picture below, my image is showed inside of the div. But I would like to show my image on the right side of the div (outer).

[image]

Here is my css:

```
.outer-gray
{
width: auto;
border: 1px solid #efefed;
border-collapse: collapse;
margin-right: 20px;
display:block;
background: transparent url('Images/framework-asp-net-mvc3.png') no-repeat bottom right;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Related : [Attach images on all four corner of DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306087/attach-images-on-all-four-corner-of-div) & [Smart way to add corner image to DIV border on all four corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467063/smart-way-to-add-corner-image-to-div-border-on-all-four-corners).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
<div class="container">
    a lot of content
    <div class="outter"></div>
</div>
<style>
    .container{position:relative}
    .outter{
        position:absolute;
        right:-10px;
        bottom:0;
        height:200px;
        width:10px;
        background:url(some.png) no-repeat
    }
</style>
```