# Attach images on all four corner of DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV which has a red dotted border all around:
[image: blank DIV]

HTML for the DIV:

```
    <div id="certificate" style="text-align:center;display:none;">
<img src="imgflo_topleft.png" id=img1 />
<img src="imgflo_bottomleft.png" id=img2 />
<img src="imgflo_topright.png" id=img3 />
<img src="imgflo_bottomright.png" id=img4 />

//OTHER texts will go here but it should not interfere with the images
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#certificate {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 2px dotted red;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Image to be placed on each corner of DIV:

[image: image to be placed no each corner]

Outcome:
[image: outcome]

Comment: Use absolute positioning. `left: 0, top: 0` for upper left; `right: 0, top: 0` for upper right; `bottom: 0, left: 0` for bottom left; `bottom: 0; right: 0` for bottom right...

Comment: So, the certificate DIV is RELATIVE and the images should be ABSOLUTE?

Comment: cant u use 1 image with all the sides as background?

Comment: It's the same image, just rotated using graphics app. I can probably use `rotate()` feature in JQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `position: relative` on your container div, and `position: absolute` on the images in conjunction with `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` pixel values, i.e:

```
#img2 { position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; }
```

Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the page flow and thus won't interfere with any other elements inside the container div (text, other graphics, headings and so on).

Or, if your container div is a fixed (set pixel value) size, just use `background-image` instead for all four corner images and save yourself some page loading time.

Comment: Simple and Easy! Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

You can do this with background images, without creating extra elements.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZD2f/).

```
.cert {
  min-width: 212;
  min-height: 166;
  background: 
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghI7u.png) left -106px top -83px no-repeat, 
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghI7u.png) right -106px top -83px no-repeat, 
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghI7u.png) left -106px bottom -83px no-repeat, 
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghI7u.png) right -106px bottom -83px no-repeat, 
    white;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

Also, you can combine the four corner images for faster downloads:

[image: combined border images]

Answer (score 0):

If your div has a fix width, you can manage it with two divs and two background images:

HTML:

```
<div class="topDiv">
     <div class="botDiv">
           content goes here
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topDiv {
    background: url( topImage.gif ) center top no-repeat;
}
.botDiv{
    background: url( bottomImage.gif) center bottom no-repeat;
}
```

If your div has a fluid width, you could use the same technik, but then with four divs.

It's no clean method, but it works.