# How do you create a perfectly scalable button in HTML/CSS3/jQuery/Javascript using images to provide borders and corners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you create a perfectly scalable button in HTML/CSS3/jQuery+Plugins using images to provide borders and corners?

I have thought of a method that is absolutely messy, and I believe there are much better ways to solve the problem.

My method involves something like this:

```
<div class="button-container">  

    // The corners are all the same image, just rotated for the specific corner
    // (using CSS)

    <div class="top-right"></div>
    <div class="bottom-right"></div>
    <div class="top-left"></div>
    <div class="bottom-left"></div>


    // The (height, width) of the top/bottom edge are (5px,1px), so they can
    // repeat-x (or be stretched infinitely with no loss of quality), likewise
    // for the left/right edges, they can repeat-y (or again be stretched).

    <div class="top-edge"></div>
    <div class="bottom-edge"></div>
    <div class="left-edge"></div>
    <div class="right-edge"></div>


    // This simply fills the center of the button, with padding on every
    // edge to allow for transparency on the corners.

    <div class="center-fill"></div>
</div>
```

People who can solve my problem see where that is going.

More info/clarification provided on request.

Edit: Not sure why you'd need a fiddle, my method is pretty self explanatory, and if you can't figure it out [Smart way to add corner image to DIV border on all four corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467063/smart-way-to-add-corner-image-to-div-border-on-all-four-corners)

That doesn't solve my problem though, my method is exactly what I do not what to use. I am trying to make an button that is scalable, similarly to how pure CSS3 buttons are scalable. If I want the top edge border of my image to be a 1-pixel wide 5-pixel high image that is stretched horizontally or repeated on the x-axis, I must use an image. I want an elegant solution to constructing a button out of images and CSS 'tricks'.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle. The problem you're trying to solve is not obvious.

Comment: I think this is just too much HTML / CSS to create 1 button. What would you want to do this?

Comment: Another method could be to generate the layers of the images using 10s of divs per edge/corner, but that is a huge issue for many reasons.

Comment: Hold up I'll provide further elaboration.

Comment: I would want to do this so I don't have to create a separate, differently sized graphic for each button, thus reducing bandwidth and time consumption, without sacrificing quality on stretching things in ways they're not meant to be stretched.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If there still isn't enough information for you, you could try re-reading the question.

Comment: @Jexah nice attitude. You'll go far. Your question was unclear because you didn't state why the current `border` CSS properties would not suit your needs.

Comment: I said I needed to use images, at no point did I say the current `border` CSS properties did not suit my needs. I think picking a question you can't answer, then asking them to provide a fiddle for something that is irrelevant to the answer of the question is arrogant and rude. Discussion for another day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using border images, an great example is given here:

http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/

```
border-image: url(border.png) 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch;
```

[image: http://www.css3.info/images/border-image1.gif]

You can use different images for the corners like this:

```
border-image:
    border-top-image
    border-right-image
    border-bottom-image
    border-left-image

border-corner-image:
    border-top-left-image
    border-top-right-image
    border-bottom-left-image
    border-bottom-right-image
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this is exactly what I wanted. I'll upvote then accept after I try it.

Comment: Good luck integrating this in your code, there is another great webpage I found explaining this css3 trick: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Comment: Thanks, got it working perfectly, thanks to a combination of both your links, your suggestion with border images, and the w3schools documentation.