# How can I place a div in <form> at the bottom right corner of modal dialog?

Tags: html, css

I know that this kind of questions already been asked in the site but my situation is different. I am designing a responsive chat application and I want to make the sign up form in a `modal dialog` that I create using `html` and `css` and `JS`.In the modal content I have a header containing a heading `<h1>` ,and bellow it a sign up form.

In the form I have two buttons and I want to place them at the bottom right corner of the modal dialog. I tried to position the parent div as relative and then position the child div as absolute with the properties : right:0; bottom:0; but that did not work. Also tried positioning the child div as fixed but then I got it out of the modal being at the bottom right of the window.

HTML:

```
 <!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <form>
      <div class="p-div">
        <labe>Email:</labe>
        <input type="text" name="email" required>

        <div class="c-div">
          <button type="button">Reset</button>
          <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    /* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: block; 
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    margin: 8% auto; 
    border-radius: 1px;
    width: 88.7%; 
    height: 89.3%;

}

.p-div{
  padding: 16px; 
  position: relative;
}

input{
  display:block;
}

.c-div{
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnzho4zo/6/)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: please include what you've tried here, not just a link to a fiddle (though the fiddle is good to have in addition). Also, if you could create an image of what you want it to look like, that would help a lot.

Comment: @j08691 I updated the fiddle..thanks

Comment: This is working as it should. `.p-div` also is `position: relative`, so the div with the buttons are being placed in relation to that div. If you remove the positioning from that div, the buttons will be placed in relation to the next ancestor with positioning.

Comment: @brouxhaha but still did not work for me !

Comment: If you want it positioned relatively to the `.modal-content`, you need to add `position: relative` to that div and not remove positioning from the divs in between the two. `https://jsfiddle.net/vnzho4zo/8/`

Comment: @brouxhaha thank you very much it worked :))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place a img in the right bottom corner of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476425/how-to-place-a-img-in-the-right-bottom-corner-of-a-div)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fork of your fiddle, I broke the c-div out of the p-div container and then absolutely positioned it.

https://jsfiddle.net/e1z07xat/3/

```
.c-div {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 165px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for replaying but when I stretch the window it gets out of the modal

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add position: relative; to the modal-container to set the bounds for the absolute positioning. I have just updated: https://jsfiddle.net/e1z07xat/